# TortoiseGit's "Clean up" leaves ignored folders, command line doesn't

Tags: git, tortoisegit

If I run TortoiseGit's "Clean up" command with -fxd options, ignored folders (and files within) are not deleted. But if I run "git clean -fxd" at the command line, they are removed. Shouldn't these behave the same, or is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: What's the git command in TortoiseGit progress dialog when you execute clanup?

Comment: What does Tortoise show you if you click on "Dry run" additionally? I just tested locally and ignored directories were removed with contents correctly.

Comment: TortoiseGit shows the same flags I mentioned, aside from the dry-run flag needed to see the command-line. "-fx -d" and "-fxd" behave the same. It's my understanding that TortoiseGit calls the command-line git I'm using, so I'm puzzled. TortoiseGit 1.8.11.0, git version 1.9.4.msysgit.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it doesn't seem to be happening today. So, I'll chalk it up to a fluke (maybe locked files or something) unless I see it again. The troubleshooting comments on the question were good.